# Finding flights to Cuba with a flight search engine

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, cuba, flight-search-engines

Several of the main flight search tools (Kayak, matrix.itasoftware.com) and the like either won't show or tell you they can't show flights to Cuba due to legal reasons and them being American websites.

Is there a search tool that will? I realise I could go to LAN or Copa or other airline's individual websites, but I'd rather there be an easier way to find flights from, say, DFW to HAV (yes I realise it'd most likely have to go  through another country first).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/) also finds plenty of flights to Cuba. (By KLM, Air Canada, Aeroflot, Air France, etc). [Skyscanner Ltd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyscanner) is based in Edinburgh, Scotland.

I tried DFW–HAV too, and yes, it found connections (through MEX, mostly):

[image]

Comment: despegar.com, on the other hand, did *not* find flights to Cuba (it won't recognise Havana as destination), which surprised me a little.

Comment: So weird, when I tried it it wasn't showing me any. Although I tried it from DFW - maybe they just won't calculate American routes for me.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering whether you get different results if you're physically located in the US. (I did try "changing my country" to US and still got the same results.) If so, a non-US proxy could be used to bypass the limitation, I suppose.

Comment: I'm in Canada, but interesting idea. I'll load up my proxy tonight :)

Answer (score 6):

Try [Momondo](http://www.momondo.dk/). It's a Danish site, but also has an English interface. I can find flights to Cuba just fine.

Answer (score 5):

[DoHop](http://dohop.com) will happily show you flights to/from Cuba.

Comment: +1, works fine, and found some pretty good prices too (e.g. HEL–HAV return trip starting < 700€).