# Can a non-US citizen living in the US on a J1 visa travel to Cuba?

Tags: visas, cuba, j1-visas

I am a non-US citizen on a J1 visa doing an internship in the US. I would like to know if it's still possible for me to travel to Cuba, via Charter Flights in Miami, for example.

Am I subject to the same restrictions as US citizens?
Could my re-entry be denied upon arrival from Havana?

Comment: Also, I am on a J1 visa. Could my re-entry be denied upon arrival from Havana?

Comment: Denied?  Probably not but expect to have a rather long and painful reentry procedure.

Answer (score 5):

No, you're not subject to it - it's the US who has put an embargo on trips to Cuba for their citizens.  However, you may have difficulty finding a flight there from the US, as commercial flights generally don't fly there.

I have heard of charter flights doing it, but the most common route is ex-Canada or Mexico - fly there first, then connect to a flight to Havana.

The issue here is many flight search engines (eg Kayak) won't show you flights there, but thankfully there are [still other sites that can display available flights](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/12787/101).

Comment: To be clear, US citizens and _permanent residents_ are restricted by the embargo: http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/cuba.txt

Comment: J1 is an exchange student.

Comment: If you ever want to convert to a green card, it might not help your cause when they see a Cuba stamp in your passport.  (Although I travelled to Cuba when I was living in Britain, and got a green card without problem.)