# How to obtain tickets for Cancun to Havana flight?

Tags: air-travel, mexico, cuba, cancun, havana

Everywhere I've looked, websites just state to buy a ticket when in Cancun, but where can I do this? Are there offices in Cancun or do I have to go to Cancun airport and go directly to Aeromexico or Cubana desk?

Comment: Have you checked at the airport?

Comment: @Karlson That's not possible seeing that I'm in another country at the moment and that I've yet to depart for my trip.

Comment: Could you not buy it online instead? [How to buy a ticket to Cuba online](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12787/finding-flights-to-cuba-with-a-flight-search-engine?rq=1)?

Comment: @MarkMayo Yeah, I already tried it, but my credit card was rejected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cubajet.com](http://www.cubajet.com/routes_cuba_flights/cancun_to_havana.asp) to buy tickets online. This service supports payment by Visa and MasterCard. Also you may use Maestro card.

As alternative, you always may buy tickets directly in airport. There are [official desks of Cubana and Airmexico airlines](http://www.asur.com.mx/en/airports/cancun/cancun-passengers/airlines-links-and-tours.html) inside International Airport of Cancun.

But remember to buy ticket at least 4-5 days before the flight. When you buy ticket on the same date - it costs much more.

Comment: I thought buying tickets on stand by (same day, last minute) was the cheapest? (Assuming they aren't sold out).